# csurf : How can we pass the csrf token to the client without inserting it into a template view?

Tags: security, express, cookies, csrf

I'm not using a templating language like handlebars or view (I bundle client-side code) and so I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I can send a csrf token without passing it into a view.

Almost all examples inject the token server-side like so:

```
app.get('/form', csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
  // pass the csrfToken to the view
  res.render('send', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})
```

I'm not entirely sure if the injection is necessary for the security mechanism to work properly.

Note: I'm set the cookie option to true, and the cookie parser is being called before csurf - yet I still get **ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token**(I believe it happens because I was sending _csrf secret back as the token, but I guess it sends the secret,_csrf, and also we have to send the csrf token along with it.

Question:

Are there other acceptable ways to send the csrf token to the client(e.g. headers,cookies,res.body, etc..)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use cookies. Make sure you define the below code before your routes. Do it like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next)=> {

  var token = req.csrfToken();
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token);
  res.locals.csrfToken = token;

  next();
});

app.post('/someroute', (req, resp)=>{

//..processing something...

})
```

This whay you will have a cookie on your client side with the generated token. This token will be updated for every request.
To add this token to an ajax request, you just need to read the cookie and pass the token to the request. e.g using axios:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['x-csrf-token'] = readCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
axios.post('/someroute', {somedata})
```

Comment: This works great for a React Express stack. Also, prevents having to insert the token into every html request manually since Axios default is set to sniff the token.. Nice